# Running a quicker calculation

Tags: r, performance, loops

I have 2 data frames in R, one of which is a subset of the other. I had to do some manipulations in it, and calculate the % of the subsetted data from the main data frame for 6 x-values (DayTreat in the code). So I created a function to do the calculation and create a new column.  My issue is that it's painfully slow. Any suggestions?

```
percDay <- function(fullDat, subDat)
{
  subDat$DaySum <- NULL
  for (i in fullDat$DayTreat) # for each DayTreat value in fullDat. Must be `psmelt()` made phyloseq object
  {
    r <- sum(fullDat$Abundance[fullDat$DayTreat == i])  # Take the sum of all the taxa for that day
    subDat$DaySum[subDat$DayTreat == i] <- r  # Add the value to the subset of data
  }
  subDat$DayPerc <- (subDat$Abundance/subDat$DaySum) # Make the percentage of the subset
  subDat
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [using a profiler](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) to identify the bottlenecks? Also, a reproducible example will help us help you.

Comment: Can you add example data set?

Answer (score 1):

Examing your code, it looks like that you are doing redundant calculasions
the line:

```
for (i in fullDat$DayTreat)
```

should be:

```
for (i in unique(fullDat$DayTreat))
```

After that you could use data.table and do not use separate data frames,
if you say that one is subset of onother

```
require(data.table)
setDT(fullDat)
fullDat[, subsetI := Abundance > 30] # for example, should be your Condition
fullDat[, DaySum:= sum(Abundance), by = DayTreat]
fullDat[, DayPerc := Abundance/DaySum]
# get subset:
fullDat[subsetI == T]
```

If you would provide example data and desired output, it could be possible to supply more concrete code.

Answer (score 0):

So, at a high level, I think the solutions are:

- Use faster data classes if you aren't already
- Avoid for loops

  - vectorize manually or
  - real on faster functions/libraries that use more C code and/or have more vectorization "under the hood"
- Try data.table and/or tidyverse for greater speed and cleaner code
- Benchmark and profile your code

Example:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(data.table)

percDay <- function(fullDat, subDat)
{
  subDat$DaySum <- NULL
  for (i in fullDat$DayTreat) # for each DayTreat value in fullDat. Must be `psmelt()` made phyloseq object
  {
    r <- sum(fullDat$Abundance[fullDat$DayTreat == i])  # Take the sum of all the taxa for that day
    subDat$DaySum[subDat$DayTreat == i] <- r  # Add the value to the subset of data
  }
  subDat$DayPerc <- (subDat$Abundance/subDat$DaySum) # Make the percentage of the subset
  subDat
}

# My simulation of your data.frame:
fullDat <- data.frame(Abundance=rnorm(200),
                      DayTreat=c(1:100,1:100))
subDat  <- dplyr::sample_frac(fullDat, .25)

# Your function modifies the data, so I'll make a copy. For a potential 
#   speed improvement I'll try data.table class
fullDat0 <- as.data.table(fullDat)
subDat0  <- as.data.table(subDat)


require(rbenchmark)
benchmark("original" = {
  percDay(fullDat, subDat)
},
"example_improvement" = {

  # Tidy approach
  tmp <- fullDat0 %>% 
    group_by(DayTreat) %>% 
    summarize(DaySum = sum(Abundance))

  subDat0         <- merge(subDat, tmp, by="DayTreat")  # could use semi_join
  subDat0$DayPerc <- (subDat0$Abundance/subDat0$DaySum) # could use mutate

},
replications = 100,
columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
            "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))
```

> ```
>                  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
>  example_improvement          100    0.22    1.000      0.22     0.00
>             original          100    1.42    6.455      1.23     0.01
> ```

Typically a data.table approach is going to have the greatest speed. The tibble-based "tidy" approach has clearer syntax whilst typically being faster than data.frame but slower than data.table. An experienced data.table expert like @akrun could offer a maximal performance solution using probably just 1 single data.table statement.

Comment: @akrun Care to prove my reference to you right/wrong? This question seems cut out for your talents.